# Comparar varias Listas, y que salga la de mayor valor guardado (mayor a menor)

Tags: python, python-3.7

soy algo nuevo en python, bueno deje los estudios y volvi de nuevo, tengo el siguiente proyecto de la Universidad, se supone que es un restaurante.
Dejare lo que dice del proyecto y el avance que llevo. Estoy guardando los valores que ingresa los usuarios en listas, pero como las ordeno de mayor a menor acorde a lo que ingreso el usuario, como hago para decir esas listas son de X mesa. Saludos

```
####Numero de ordenes mayor a 4 pero menor a 10
while numeroOrdenes>10 or numeroOrdenes<4:
print("** ERROR: DEBE INGRESAR UNA CANTIDAD DE ORDENES MAYOR A 4 PERO MENOR 10 ** ")
print(f"USUARIO INGRESO: {numeroOrdenes}")
numeroOrdenes = int(input("-> CANTIDAD DE ORDENES PARA PROCESAMIENTO (ENTER): "))
print("->INSTRUCCIONES: Ingrese para cada número de orden el número de mesa (ENTER). ")
###Acorde el usuario ingresa la orden tiene que ingresar el numero de mesa, lo que estoy haciendo es guardando las ordenes
### por mesa, y que me las guarde en listas
ordenCeroMesaCeroLista = []
ordenUnoMesaUnoLista = []
ordenDosMesaDosLista = []
ordenTresMesaTresLista = []
ordenCuatroMesaCuatroLista = []
ordenCincoMesaCincoLista = []
ordenSeisMesaSeisLista = []
for contadorOrden in range(0,numeroOrdenes):
    valorMesa = int(input(f"# Orden {contadorOrden}: "))
if valorMesa==0:
    ordenCeroMesaCeroLista.append(valorMesa)
if valorMesa==1:
    ordenUnoMesaUnoLista.append(valorMesa)
if valorMesa==2:
    ordenDosMesaDosLista.append(valorMesa)
if valorMesa==3:
    ordenTresMesaTresLista.append(valorMesa)
if valorMesa==4:
    ordenCuatroMesaCuatroLista.append(valorMesa)
if valorMesa==5:
    ordenCincoMesaCincoLista.append(valorMesa)
    ###Lista 0-5
if valorMesa == 6:
    ordenSeisMesaSeisLista.append(valorMesa)
while valorMesa<0 or valorMesa>6:
    print("** ERROR: NO TENEMOS TANTAS MESAS EN NUESTRO RESTAURANTE. NUESTRAS MESAS VAN DESDE LA 0-14 ** ")
    print(f"USUARIO INGRESO: {valorMesa}")
    valorMesa = int(input("->INSTRUCCIONES: Ingrese para cada número de orden el número de mesa (ENTER). "))
contadorOrden+=1
print("** REPORTE: FRECUENCIA DE MESAS (Mayor a menor frecuencia)**: ")
print(len(ordenCeroMesaCeroLista))
print(len(ordenUnoMesaUnoLista))
print(len(ordenDosMesaDosLista))
print(len(ordenTresMesaTresLista))
print(len(ordenCuatroMesaCuatroLista))
print(len(ordenCincoMesaCincoLista))
print(len(ordenSeisMesaSeisLista))
```

[image: Esto es el proyecto y como tiene que quedar]

Answer (score 0):

Manejar como VECTOR osea lista dentro de otra lista de la siguiente manera.

```
//        mesa:ordenes      mesa:ordenes
mesas = [ [ 1,  2 ],        [ 2,  10] ]
```

El codigo quedaria asi

```py
lista_mesas = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0]]
index_mesa = 0 # el numero de mesa es la posición 0
index_ordenes = 1 # la cantidad de ordenes en la posición 1
contador_ordenes = 0
maximas_ordenes = 12

while contador_ordenes < maximas_ordenes:
  mesa = int(input("Ingresa Numero de Mesa: "))
  try:
    ordenes = int(input("Ingresa Cantidad Ordenes: "))
    lista_mesas[mesa - 1][index_ordenes] += ordenes
    contador_ordenes += ordenes
  except:
    print('Mesa u Orden No Valida')
print(lista_mesas)

mesa_mas_frecuente = lista_mesas[0]
for mesa in lista_mesas:
  if mesa[index_ordenes] > mesa_mas_frecuente[index_ordenes]:
    mesa_mas_frecuente = mesa
print('Mas Solicitada Mesa: ',str(mesa_mas_frecuente[index_mesa]), ' Ordenes: ', str(mesa_mas_frecuente[index_ordenes]))
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono. Como hago para imprimir los valores de cada mesa de mayor a menor, edite para que saliera la de menor frecuencia me guíe con lo que usted hizo